# Bash Script to create a file for each unique permission in a listing/find command and printing each directory/file path instance of that permission

Tags: shell-script, files, permissions, sort

I'm trying to create a bash script that will be able to perform a find command to get the permissions and full path of every file/directory in a directory tree and create a file for each unique permission and printing each full file path to that permissions file.  Then in the future I could read these files and use them to permissions to the way they were when I ran the script.

For instance:

```
drwxrwxrwx /home/user/testDirectory  
-rwxrwxrwx /home/user/testDirectory/testFile  
drwxr-xr-x /home/user/testDirectory/directory2  
-rwxr-xr-x /home/user/testDirectory/directory2/test2
```

The above would create 2 files (e.g. `777.txt` and `755.txt`) that would each have 2 of the lines.

I am struggling with the logic to create a file for each unique permission and then send the full file path.

What I have so far (I doubt the array is necessary, but I have played with sorting the array by permission which I can do with -k 1.2 on the sort command to ignore the d flag):

```
declare -a PERMS

i=0

while read line
do
     PERMS[$i]="$line"
     (( i++ ))
done < <( find /opt/sas94 -printf ""%M/" "%p/"\n")
```

Comment: Can we assume that none of your directory or file names will contain a newline character?

Comment: Since directory and file names can easily contain one or more spaces I'd suggest you put the permissions number/string as the first item and the path name as the remainder of the line.

Comment: Yes no newline characters.  The permissions are the first thing printed by the find command.  Looking at my initial post I realize the format screwed up for the example output of the file command.  But each line starts with a permission and then the full path.  One combo per line.

Comment: What is going on with your quotes “`-printf ""%M/" "%p/"\n"`”?

Comment: Apparently, the ones around the %M and %p are unnecessary.  It works both as ""%M/" "%p/"\n" and "%M/ %p/\n".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read file; do
        stat -c '%A %n' "$file" >> $(stat -c '%a' "$file").txt
done < <(find "$1")
```

Usage:

```
./script.sh /path/to/directory
```

- the first `stat -c '%A %n' "$file"` prints the permissions and path to the file, e.g. `-rw-rw-rw- /foo/bar`
- the second `stat -c '%a' "$file"` prints the permissions in octal form, e.g. `666`

The output of the first `stat` is appended to the filename created by the second `stat` with suffix `.txt`.

Comment: Thank you! This works great.